# Monitor traffic by ip

Tags: networking, monitoring

I have machines with one interface eth0 with multiple different IP addresses attached to it (255) to be exact, interfaces look like this eth0:1, eth0:2 ...eth0:254.

I want to monitor the traffic for each IP whit Prometheus + Grafana (or at least visualize it in Grafana).

So far I managed to get the overall traffic of the eth0 interface. I tried with SNMP, but still I can get overall traffic only.
I also looked up how `iotop` calculates traffic of each IP and it looks like it opens each packet and check the ip address inside of it.

Using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Depending on what you use those IP addresses for, you could also replace them with applications running in a network namespaces, connect up the namespaces via a veth pair, and measure traffic on the veth pair. Then you'll be able to distinguish by interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

`eth0:1`, `eth0:2` etc are not virtual interfaces, the colon and number part is just a label associated with one of the multiple addresses assigned to the interface. This label is required by old tools, but it is not needed by modern tools like `ip`. You will have to use a monitoring tool that can filter traffic by IP address if you want to separate them.